# Can't switch from Full screen mode to Maximize mode when automating IE using Selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver

Someone help me.

This is my code.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "D:\\Personal\\others\\New folder\\Selenium\\Software\\Software\\drivers\\IEDriverServer.exe");
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.get("http://facebook.com");
driver.manage().window().fullscreen();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

I used Fullscreen method followed by maximize method. Once the screen went into fullscreen it did not switch back to maximize mode even, if I manually pressed F11 after the automation script completed. This scenario works in other browsers.

Comment: why do you wanna do that ? why not `driver.manage().window().maximize();` is your first choice ?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need of going to full screen if you want your browser to get maximize.

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

This code will let you maximize your browser during the run.
If you want to resize your window to a specific size in that case you can use the following:

```
Dimension d = new Dimension(420,600);
driver.manage().window().setSize(d);
```

This will let you resize your browser as per the height and width that you are providing.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thank you Karthikeyan.. but my question is like why .maximize method not working after .full screen method executed in IE browser specifically, if we do in other browser its working fine even edge browser also working fine. but IE once browser went into full screen mode then maximizing mode is not working.

Comment: which IEDriver version are you using?